# ionic 2 storage does not work properly

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using ionic 2 with storage.

I developed an E-commerce app.

If any product adds to cart I will store the product using storage.

Here is my function

```
//Add to cart

   addItemToCarts(item)
   {

      this.items.push(item);
      this.storage.set('products',this.items);

   }
```

It's work and also I display the badge count Which means `products`   length.

Get `storage(products)` length .Here is my code

```
//Get cart Count

    this.storage.get('products').then((data) => {
     if(data != null)
     {
       this.badge='';
       this.badge=data.length;
       this.Cartproducts=data;
       console.log("data");
       console.log(data);
     }
    });
```

If I remove any product in the cart.Using this code and again set to Storage.

Here is my code

```
cancel(i)
  {
    console.log(i);
    this.Cartproducts.splice(i, 1);
    var item=this.Cartproducts;
    this.length=this.Cartproducts.length;
    console.log(this.Cartproducts);
    this.storage.remove('products');
    this.storage.set('products',item);
  }
```

Example My cart page products length is 3.If I remove any one product and the length is 2.and badge count also 2.

If again I add any one product.The storage products length is 4 why?.

But actually, the Storage products length is 3.Is right?

I don't have any idea.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks.

Comment: When you cancel an item, you update `this.length` but not `this.badge`. When you get storage count, this is the contrary. However, you say that when you cancel an item, both values are updated. I think that you didn't share enough code for us to see the whole picture. Like nothing tells us that the count is updated when you add an item with `addItemToCarts`. We are missing the link between your code parts.

Answer (score 0):

I think `addItemToCarts` has some problem. You are pushing data in `this.items` in `addItemToCarts` function and you are removing item from `Cartproducts` array in `Cancel` function and storing. Ideally your function 'addItemToCarts' should look like below.

```
//Add to cart
addItemToCarts(item)
{
  this.Cartproducts.push(item);
  this.storage.set('products',this.Cartproducts);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.But still Not fix this issue.